# KIvyMD needs "Boxshadow" how do i use it/import it

Tags: python, css, kivy, kivymd

in KivyMD there is a module or something called "Boxshadow", I need it to use almost every widget which uses levitation and i couldn't find anything resolving this issue. I am just a beginner with Kivy and KivyMD especially therefore I would be truly thankful for a solution. I as well cant follow simple tutorials because something does not work for me which works for them.

The simplest Application:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.config import Config
import kivy
from kivy.core.window import Window



Window.size = (200, 425)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
         self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
         self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple"
         return Builder.load_file('Mainapplication.kv')

 MainApp().run()
```

Kivy:

```
MDScreen:

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Knopf"
        pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.8}
```

ERROR Raised:

```
   File "C:\KivyMD\virtual\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 147, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
  kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <BoxShadow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

```
python3 -m pip remove kivymd

pip install kivymd==1.0.2
```

And everything worked.